# Draw a simple bracket and/or arc diagram

Tags: diagrams

I would like to be able to draw something similar to the attached example.  I'm fairly new to latex but have done some straight prose before.  It would need to convey the general idea but wouldn't have to look exactly the same.  Can someone point me in the right direction (e.g. what package(s) to use)?  Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: You can do that with TikZ. See the section about edges from parents in the TikZ manual (`texdoc tikz`).

Answer (score 2):

This is one possible solution where a macro `VerticalBracket` is defined that takes 7 arguments, including a color option.

[image]

Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\newcommand{\tikzmark}[1]{\tikz[overlay,remember picture,baseline={-3pt}] \node[] (#1) {};}

\newcommand\VerticalBraket[7][]{%
    % #1 = draw options
    % #2 = top mark
    % #3 = bottom mark
    % #4 = label
    % #5 = x adjustment 
    % #6 = labe at upper corner
    % #7 = label at lower corner
\draw[#1] 
(#2) node[above left,]{#6} -- ++(-1.2 cm,0)|- node[pos=0.3,left=2mm] {#4} ([xshift=-#5]#3.west)
node [above left] {#7};
}
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
\item[\tikzmark{1a}1a] Those under the yoke of slavery should consider their own masters wotthy of all honor
\begin{itemize}
\item[\tikzmark{1b} 1b] in order that the same of God should not be sopken against\\
\item[\tikzmark{1c}1c] and  that the teaching should not be soken against
\end{itemize}
\item[\tikzmark{2a} 2a] That is, those slaves who have believing masters should not despise them
\begin{itemize}
\item[\tikzmark{2b} 2b] becaue they are brothers
\end{itemize}
\item[\tikzmark{2c} 2c] but instead, they should serve their believing masters
\begin{itemize}
\item[\tikzmark{2d} 2d] becaue those benefiting from the good work are believers and beloved
\end{itemize}
\end{itemize}

\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture]
\VerticalBraket[ultra thick, blue]{1b}{1c}{\tikzmark{s}S}{1ex}{}{}
\VerticalBraket[ultra thick, blue]{2a}{2b}{\tikzmark{-}}{5ex}{}{G}
\VerticalBraket[ultra thick, blue]{2c}{2d}{\tikzmark{+}}{5ex}{}{G}
\VerticalBraket[draw=none]{1a}{1a}
{\tikzmark{ac}}{0ex}{}{}
\VerticalBraket[ultra thick, blue]{ac}{s}
{\tikzmark{id}}{3ex}{Ac}{Pur}
\VerticalBraket[ultra thick, blue]{-}{+}
{\tikzmark{exp}}{0ex}{$-$}{$+$}
\VerticalBraket[ultra thick, blue]{id}{exp}
{}{0ex}{Id}{Exp}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```